# Multiple input neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings

I'm currently working on a social media analysis and trying to predict the tendency to a healthy lifestyle by a social media profile from [Vkontakte](http://vk.com).

There are several papers on this topic on the web, but mostly they are using "classic" approaches like TF-IDF + numerical data -> SVM/RandomForest. I wonder if it is possible to train a multihead NN for this task with a structure like [image: this]?

Any papers/blog posts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you suggest in the scheme looks good. Just implemented and will work fine.